# Texstudio side panel does not show proper symbols but some strange charactors

Tags: texstudio

[image]
TexStudio side panel does not show proper symbols but some strange characters. I have tried all the suggestions that I could muster from the net. My system is laptop with i5 12gb ram, on manjaro linux 17.1.1.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you specify your problem a little bit?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Your edit went for Review, which likely means you've got two separate accounts, and thus cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: In your texstudio `preferences->General->Appearance`: which font is selected?